# File and Folder Manipulation in Powershell

Tags: file, powershell, file-management

I have a folder of thousands of filenames.

All filenames are relative to a user's userID. Some users have multiple files in this folder, so it appends a number onto the end of the name. I.E. susy.txt, susy1.txt, susy2.txt, carl.txt, carl1.txt, etc...

What I am trying to do is create a specific folder for each user that has multiple files, and move all associated files into that folder. So I notice there are multiple susy documents. So I want to create a folder named Susy and place susy.txt, susy1.txt, and susy2.txt into it... And so on for all files.

Is it even possible to do this as a batch file, if so can someone point me in the correct direction on doing this? I have a small amount of knowledge in writing batch scripts, and would like to take this as an opportunity to learn more.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simpler/more compact way of doing it:

```
Get-ChildItem | ?{$_.Name -match '(\D+)\d*\.txt'} | %{
  md $matches[1] -ea SilentlyContinue 
  Move-Item $_ $matches[1]
}
```

A purist might say that it's "better practice" to **Test-Path** before attempting to create the directory, but I generally prefer more compact code; if no other decisions hinge on whether the directory already exists, it's quicker to just attempt to create it each time and ignore errors.

---

A couple of explanatory notes, in response to the OP's comment:

- `?{ }` is shorthand for **Where-Object**, which filters on a condition, i.e. only objects that meet the specified condition are passed down the pipeline. So in this case, it takes the listing of the current directory and selects only the objects whose **Name** property matches the regex.
- After the **-match** operator is used, the matches are stored in the automatic array variable **$matches**. **$matches[0]** contains the entire matched part of the string, and indices starting with 1 contain the match groups, numbered from the ordinal position of the left parenthesis, i.e. **$matches[1]** is the match group beginning with the first left parenthesis encountered, **$matches[2]** is the match group beginning with the second left parenthesis, etc.

  In this case there is only one match group, and **$matches[1]** contains the part of the string matched by `(\D+)`, i.e. the sequence of consecutive non-digit characters prior to the first digit or dot.

Comment: Okay, this worked Amazing and just how I want it to. Thank you! I am obviously not a powershell pro, however I understand this for the most part... I just don't know what the ?{} means and $matches[1]. Mainly the [1], I don't understand. Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you again! Makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my quick-and-dirty just trumped up solution.  It uses a regular expression to split the users name out of the filename, i.e. the expression will split `carl` out of `carl1.txt` `carl3.txt` `carl22.txt`.  It then creates folders from those names, uniquely.  So it only tries to create `carl` once, not 57 times.  After that, it moves all the `carl` and `johnny` and `susy` etc., into the new folders.

If you're new, don't be afraid if this seems a little intimidating.  Especially regular expressions.  There's almost certainly a way to do this without them, if they're confusing to you, but regular expressions are one of those tools that once you learn it you're aware of just how great it is at solving things.

```
[regex]$pattern_name = '^\w.+?(?=[\d\.])'

# create folders for all the unique users
get-Childitem -File -path 'c:\scripts' | foreach-Object {$pattern_name.match($_).value } | sort -unique | foreach-Object { mkdir $_ }

# move files into those folders
get-Childitem -File -path 'c:\scripts' | foreach-Object {
    $user = $pattern_name.match($_).value 
    Move-Item -destination ".\$user" -Path $_.FullName
    }
```

Comment: +1 - Note that this will create a directory for a user even if they only have a single file, which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: Agreed.  Though it's likely what they wanted :P

Comment: A couple of issues with that regex...not major ones, but I'm wondering why you wrote it that way. (1) Why the `.` after the `\w` in the regex? While it's not *likely* that a name would be only one character long, the OP didn't specify at least two characters. Also, why are you requiring only the first character in particular to be in the \w class, and after that matching any character until the first digit or period?

Comment: It was just a quick and dirty pattern based of the OPs initial statements, files based on peoples names with numbers at the end.  The pattern should certainly be changed to suit their precise needs.  As for matching any character after the first `\w` that was just a mistake on my part.  Though, depending on the filenames in question, it might even work out better that way, if any of the peoples names have symbols in them for instance.  Bottom line is the regex should be modified to fit their exact circumstances.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed! Tweaking the regex, got me the results I needed. I do have one question, and I may sound a tad nooby. I know the $pattern_name.match($_) returns a boolean that compares my filename to the regex... but what does adding the .value do? Other than that I understand everything perfectly fine. THANK YOU!

Comment: It breaks down like this.  `$pattern_name` is a `RegEx` object.  It has a `Match` method that you must supply a parameter to, in this case the `$_` variable which is the current filename coming down the pipeline.  Just as you say the `Match` method returns a boolean on whether the filename matches the regular expression.  Here's the interesting bit.  The `Match` method has some properties, and one of them is `Value`.  The `Value` property is the actual bit of text that satisfied the match.  So in this case, it'd be the "sam" from "sam1"

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it. What this does is:

1. Groups the files in the directory by the user's name.
2. If the group has more than one file it creates a directory for the user and then moves the user's files into that directory.

> (Note that I added the -WhatIf option to all commands that would
>   modify data - you will have to remove them to actually modify the
>   data.)

```
# Make backup for safety
cp -recurse .\userFiles .\userFilesBackup

cd .\userFiles

gci | `

select-object @{n='User';e={$_.BaseName -replace "^([a-z]+)[\d]*$", '$1'}}, Name | `

group-object User | `

? { $_.Count -gt 1 } | `

% { `

$userDirectory = $_.Name
mkdir -WhatIf $userDirectory

foreach ($f in $_.Group)
{ mv -WhatIf $f.Name $userDirectory }

}
```