# Move and Manipulate files across directories - Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am trying to move a list of files from one directory to another. The catch is, When the items are moved to the new directory, I want to automatically organize them.

Ex..
I have a folder of thousands of filenames.

All filenames are relative to a user's userID. Some users have multiple files in this folder, so it appends a number onto the end of the name. I.E. `susy.txt`, `susy1.txt`, `susy2.txt`, `carl.txt`, `carl1.txt`, etc...

What I am trying to do is create a specific folder (in the new directory) for each user that has multiple files, and move all associated files into that folder. So I notice there are multiple susy documents. So I want to create a folder named Susy and place `susy.txt`, `susy1.txt`, and `susy2.txt` into it... And so on for all files.

Is it even possible to do this as a batch file, if so can someone point me in the correct direction on doing this? I have a small amount of knowledge in writing batch scripts, and would like to take this as an opportunity to learn more.

---

This is very similar to a question I have asked earlier. [File and Folder Manipulation in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147674/file-and-folder-manipulation-in-powershell/). I am very thankful for the responses I received, they helped me greatly. The answer from **Adi Inbar** was exactly what I needed, at the time. However, I was forced to make a modification, which I have tried myself.

**Adi Inbar's Answer**

```
Get-ChildItem | ?{$_.Name -match '(\D+)\d*\.txt'} | %{
  md $matches[1] -ea SilentlyContinue 
  Move-Item $_ $matches[1]
}
```

Short sweet and too the point, exactly what I needed. However it only works for for files that are going to be organized but stay in the same parent folder.

This is what I have attempted:

```
Get-ChildItem –path "P:\My Documents\Org Test\Test1" | Where{$_.Name -match '(\D+)\d*\.txt'} | Foreach{
     md P:\'My Documents'\'Org Test'\Test2\$matches[1] -ea SilentlyContinue
     Move-Item $_ P:\'My Documents'\'Org Test'\Test2\$matches[1]
}
```

To my knowledge and basic understanding this should work... But I am getting an error saying Move-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

```
At P:\My Documents\Org Test\Test.ps1:3 char:3
    +      Move-Item -Path P:\'My Documents'\'Org Test'\Test1\$_ -destination P:\'M ...
    +    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (P:\My Documents...t1\Johnny123.txt:FileInfo) [Move-Item], I
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

I am sure that it is on the tip of my tongue, but I cannot get it. I have very basic powershell scripting experience and just need a quick fix.

---

**EDIT:**

I have been able to "resolve" my issue by using this script:

```
Get-ChildItem –path P:\'My Documents'\'PST Org Script'\Test1 | Foreach-Object{ 
    move-item -Path $_.fullname -Destination "P:\My Documents\PST Org Script\Test2" -ea SilentlyContinue }

cd P:\'My Documents'\'PST Org Script'\Test2

Get-ChildItem | ?{$_.Name -match '(\D+)\d*\.txt'} | %{
  md $matches[1] -ea SilentlyContinue 
  Move-Item $_ $matches[1]
}
```

I am curious. I feel like this can be done in the 3 lines of code I have above. This seems like a little redundant. But what do I know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve my issue using this:

```
Get-ChildItem –path P:\'My Documents'\'PST Org Script'\Test1 | Foreach-Object{ 
    move-item -Path $_.fullname -Destination "P:\My Documents\PST Org Script\Test2" -ea SilentlyContinue }

cd P:\'My Documents'\'PST Org Script'\Test2

Get-ChildItem | ?{$_.Name -match '(\D+)\d*\.txt'} | %{
  md $matches[1] -ea SilentlyContinue 
  Move-Item $_ $matches[1]
}
```

However I feel, there is a shorter, simpler way of doing this via some variation of the method I entered earlier in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$srcPath = 'P:\My Documents\PST Org Script\Test1'
$dstPath = 'P:\My Documents\PST Org Script\Test2'
Get-ChildItem $srcPath | Where {$_.Name -match '(\D+)\d*\.txt'} | 
    Foreach {$targetDir = Join-Path $dstPath $matches[1]
             md $targetDir -ea 0
             Move-Item $_ $targetDir -WhatIf}
```